# How do i add my sqlite database into my application during deployment if my datasource is memoy

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have tried to  publish my application after completion, but am encountering problems that include the system responding that the DB is missing.I would like to know how I can include my sqlite database in my application if its location is in the memory.My target is the client machine and im using c#.
[here is the response im getting after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T09y6.png)

```
 public void dt()
    {
        table = new SQLiteConnection("data source=memory,version=3");
        table.Open();
    }
```

Comment: posting code, snapshots or error details may help you getting faster response

Comment: please check out the snap above

Answer (score 0):

If your doing desktop application then
The simplest way is to include your db file into your project (add -> New Item, or just drag it into your project),
and in the properties window of visual studio select your db file and make sure to
set (build action) to None,
and you may set (Copy to output directory) to Copy if newer,
and don't forget to point your ConnectionString to this DB file location,
say you used hard coded connection string variable, then it's gonna be like

```
    readonly string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=YourDB.db;";
```

Now when you publish your application, your DB file will go with it.

Comment: checkout the response i got above.

Comment: @ThandolwenkosiMHETA 
whether you publish directly from vs, or use a third party installer, you have to include the two folders called x64 and x32 and the dll's inside them too(both folders have SQLite.Interop.dll version in it) you can find these folders in your project bin diractory(that if you got SQLite directly from NuGet).